# Akka in Scala, exclamation mark and question mark

Tags: scala, operators, akka, actor

What is the difference between exclamation mark (`!`) and question mark (`?`) when sending messages to Actors?

```
myActor ! Hello(value1)
myActor ? Hello(value1)
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Shamelessly copied *[awesome]* [official doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/actors.html#Send%20messages) (look **Send messages** section for more):

> Messages are sent to an Actor through one of the following methods.
>
> `!` means “fire-and-forget”, e.g. send a message asynchronously and
>   return immediately. Also known as `tell`.
>
> `?` sends a message
>   asynchronously and returns a `Future` representing a possible reply.
>   Also known as `ask`.

Comment: For anyone interested in how this was accomplished - see Operator Overloading in Scala: https://dzone.com/articles/operator-overloading-scala

Comment: ! means “fire-and-forget” It could not be more descriptive!

Answer (score 26):

From the recipient's point of view, it sees `tell` and `ask` messages the same way. However when receiving a `tell` the value of `sender` will be the reference of the actor who sent the message, whereas for an `ask`, the `sender` is set up such that any reply goes to the `Future` created in the actor who did the asking.

There is an advantage in `ask`, that it is easy to know that the response you're receiving was definitely a result of the message you asked, whereas with Tell, you may need to use unique IDs to achieve a similar result. However with `ask` you need to set a `timeout` after which the `Future` will fail if no response is received.

In the code below, the same effect is achieved with a `tell` and and `ask`.

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask

class TellActor extends Actor {

  val recipient = context.actorOf(Props[ReceiveActor])

  def receive = {
    case "Start" =>
      recipient ! "Hello" // equivalent to recipient.tell("hello", self)

    case reply => println(reply)
  }
} 

class AskActor extends Actor {

  val recipient = context.actorOf(Props[ReceiveActor])

  def receive = {
    case "Start" =>
      implicit val timeout = 3 seconds
      val replyF = recipient ? "Hello" // equivalent to recipient.ask("Hello")
      replyF.onSuccess{
        case reply => println(reply)
      }
  }
}

class ReceiveActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Hello" => sender ! "And Hello to you!"
  }
}
```